# ADFS 3.0 custom login based on relying party

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs3.0

We are planning to implement seamless single sign-on between our consumer websites and need the below features,

1. All our external users should be on separate active directory domain.
2. Users should get seamless sign-on between Java and .Net applications.
3. Login Screen should look different for each websites i.e different header & footer based on relying party region and URL.
4. Password reset should be a self service.

We are not sure whether ADFS3.0 is the right solution for us. I did  some research on ADFS features and could not find any direct documentation supporting above features.

If ADFS 3.0 is good enough please guide me on how we can achieve these features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer some questions:

2) Yes - as long as your Java and .NET applications are claims-based.

3) As per @MrADFS, OOTB for ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016). Or else, refer [Customizing the AD FS sign-in pages per relying party trust](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2015/08/29/customizing-the-ad-fs-sign-in-pages-per-relying-party-trust/).

4) Yes - refer [ADFS : Expired password](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/05/adfs-expired-password.html) and the link inside it.

Answer (score 1):

While you can do some customization via JavaScript evaluation of the URL to identify the RP, this is not a scalable solution with ADFS 2012R2 (3.0). Please check out ADFS 2016 (4.0) and which imminently close to RTM where we add support for this. You can validate on a TP5 build of server 2016.

Check the "Assigning custom web themes per RP" section at https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-user-sign-in-customization.

Tweet me @MrADFS if you need more help.

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,but our infrastructure is not ready to upgrade to server 2016 yet